# How to setup Kaltura 5.0.0 in Windows Environment using XAMPP

Tags: windows, xampp, live-streaming, kaltura

I am trying to setup Live Streaming using Kaltura. I am having Windows 7 Environment with XAMPP Server setup in my system. I find myself hard to setup Kaltura in Windows Environment. Can anyone guide me with step by step process to setup kaltura in Windows Machine.

Comment: find tutorial in Google please.

Comment: @Raptor i have searched in google. But i find no links for setting up in windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't install CE5, especially on Windows.
Try and install CE9 and not on Windows also, as your system can't go to production.
You might be able to use it as a dev environment or a test environment.

As for the installation itself, it is basically the same to use Windows or Linux, in terms of the actual code (PHP).
You need to put your code in c:/opt/kaltura/app.
Don't run the installation as it won't work on Windows.

Now you need to replace all the tokens in the system (search for @*@ on all files)
Also you would need to install Kaltura DB (located under /opt/kaltura/app/deployment)
That should be the most of the work.
Once PHP is working you need to install Sphinx search (searchd) and use it on windows.
The batch manager works on Windows (simple PHP code), but I would run it  always, only when I need it.

Also take a look here: http://kaltura.github.io/platform-install-packages/
Hope it will help you solve some of the issues.